# Count # of errors in error log & Compare | Powershell (V2) | Array Data Structures

Tags: arrays, powershell, data-structures, hashtable, powershell-2.0

I have a hashtable of error codes and the max # of times it is acceptable for them to occur across a directory of error logs. 
Like so:

```
Key    Value
err1   2
err2   1
```

This table is created dynamically based on input from a control file (xml) so the # of elements can change.

I want to now be able to look for 'err1' and 'err2', count the # of times those occur, and then compare that back to the hashtable.

so I have something like this:

```
ForEach($file in $logs){
    ForEach($key in $hashTable.keys){
        If(Select-String $file -pattern $key){
            #get key value, increment a counter for this key value (error code)
        }
    }
}

#Psuedo for next step...
<#
 ForEach($key in $hashTable.keys){
      If (CountFound > Key.Value) {
     write-host $("Error: " + $key + " occurred too much."
    }
 }
#>
```

Is there a data structure in PowerShell that is good at storing variable/value pairs that is easily and quickly modifiable?

I don't want to create an array for each key value, then add an element to that array each time I find a matching error code in a file, then count the different array's lengths. But that's the best solution I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go OO way and have class to represent each error type you read from external source and then update those error instances based on your logic. Since you asked only for the better structure to hold your data, I focused only on that. Logic you already have.

```
$errorClass = @"
public class Error
{
    public Error(string errorCode, int maxOccurances) {
        ErrorCode = errorCode;
        MaxOccurances = maxOccurances;
    }

    public string ErrorCode;
    public int MaxOccurances;
    public int ActualOccurances;
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $errorClass

$error1 = New-Object Error("Err1", 2) # You get these values from xml
$error1.ActualOccurances = 5 # Update this property based on your logic

$error2 = New-Object Error("Err2", 1)
$error2.ActualOccurances = 3

$errArray = @($error1, $error2)

foreach ($err in $errArray) {
    if ($err.ActualOccurances -gt $err.MaxOccurances) {
        write-host $("Error: '" + $err.ErrorCode + "' occurred too much.")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Error: 'Err1' occurred too much.
Error: 'Err2' occurred too much.
```

Comment: Are classes supported in V2?

Comment: In this example, the `Error` type is implemented using C# - `Add-Type` will compile it for you at runtime. So yes, it works in PowerShell V2

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably the easiest way to obtain my goal.

```
ForEach($key in $hashTable.keys){
$count = 0
    ForEach($file in $logs){
        If(Select-String $file -pattern $key){
            $count++
        }
    }
    If($count -gt $hashTable.Get_Item($key){
        #Do something
    }
}
```

This way I avoid having another data structure entirely.